# How to draw two Y-axis with different scaling in AChartEngine

Tags: android, charts, achartengine, linechart

I have problem in drawing two Y-axis (one at right and one at left) with different scaling in AChartEngine: I want left side to be scaled from 0 to 40 which is correct, But the right side scaling is not the desire one, as it should be from 10 to 100. Please help me.

My source code look like this

public LinearLayout execute(Context context) {

```
String[] titles = new String[] { "Ciggars" };

List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
  x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7});
}

List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
values.add(new double[] { 12.3, 12.5, 13.8, 16.8, 20.4, 24.4, 26.4, 26.1, 13.9 });

// Set color of lines
int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW };
PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE, PointStyle.DIAMOND};

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(2);
setRenderer(renderer, colors, styles);
int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
}

setChartSettings(renderer, "Average Cigarates", "Days", "Cigarates", 0, 7, 0, 40, Color.LTGRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
// fragments on X and Y-axis to be divided
renderer.setXLabels(7);
renderer.setYLabels(10);
renderer.setShowGrid(true);
renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
renderer.setZoomRate(1.05f);
renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.GREEN);

renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, colors[0]);
renderer.setYLabelsColor(1, colors[1]);

renderer.setYTitle("% Tar/Nicotine", 1);
//renderer.setYTitle(title, scale)
renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 1);

XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
values.clear();

values.add(new double[] { 4.3, 4.9, 5.9, 8.8, 10.8, 11.9, 13.6, 12.8});
addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "Tar/Nicotine" }, x, values, 1);

// set background color
renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);     
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.GRAY);

GraphicalView gview = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(context, dataset, renderer, 0.3f);

LinearLayout lnr = null;
lnr = new LinearLayout(context);
lnr.addView(gview);

return lnr; }
```

Comment: Full source code can be found [here](http://naeemgik.blogspot.com/2013/09/line-chart-using-achartengine-api-in.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding these values for the series that has the Y axis on the right:

```
values.add(new double[] { 4.3, 4.9, 5.9, 8.8, 10.8, 11.9, 13.6, 12.8 });
```

As AChartEngine computes the visible range by default, the range for the Y axis is between 4.3 and 13.6.

So you have to either set your values between 10 and 100 or you have to manually modify the visible range this way:

```
renderer.setYAxisMin(10, 1);
renderer.setYAxisMax(100, 1);
```

Comment: OMG...this is what exactly i needed Thanks Dan very much!

Comment: One thing please! My first line starts from 1 while the second one starts from zero. I want both lines to be started from 1.

Comment: What do you mean it starts from 1? On which axis? Play with renderer.setXAxisMin(); APIs.

Comment: i am talking about x-axis. i want both lines to be drawn, to be start from one position that is 1.

Comment: As you are extending the AbstractDemoChart, the datasets are filled with data using the buildDataset and addXYSeries methods that add data starting from 0. Take a look at the methods and write your own code that adds data to the series. If you have more questions, please ask them separately, don't keep asking them here.

Comment: @NaeemShah hi naeem i am having the same problem of second line starts from zero...how did u solve that problem ?thanks in advance